# disconnet a smb session opened with "remember forever" option

Tags: pantheon-files, samba

I connected to a samba folder on a windows with that option.. The problem is the user I loged in doesn't have permission to manage it, so I want to log in again with another user
(Sorry for my english, is not my mother lenguage, hope the doupt is understandable!)

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect using the elementaryos file manager? You should be able to use the file manager (Files) to disconnect.  Just click the "eject" icon against your connection in the sidebar under "Network".  You should then be able to reconnect using a different name and password using the "Connect Server" dialog.